# Getting MemoryError in Jupyter but works in Spyder

Tags: python, list

I have a function that finds all combinations of a list:

```
def GetRulesCombinations(selected_list, start_index , end_index):
    AllCombinations=[]

    for i in range(start_index, end_index+1):
        AllCombinations.extend(itertools.combinations(selected_list, i))

    AllCombinations = [list(x) for x in AllCombinations]
    return AllCombinations
```

Example:

```
comb = GetRulesCombinations(range(5), 1,3)

comb = [[0],[1],...,[0, 1], [0, 2],...,[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3],...]
```

I am getting this:

```
       807     for i in range(start_index, end_index+1):
   --> 808         AllCombinations.extend(itertools.combinations(selected_list, i))
       809 
       810     AllCombinations = [list(x) for x in AllCombinations]

   MemoryError:
```

Is there any way that I can avoid this? Appreciate the help.

By the way, I am doing things like

```
GetRulesCombinations(range(27), 16,27)
len(GetRulesCombinations(range(27),16,27))
29666704
```

Comment: Jupyter uses more memory compare to ipython.

Comment: Are you calling this function a lot of times? Note, Jupyter notebooks maintain references to objects if you just plop them out into the REPL, which would prevent garbage collection...

Comment: I only call this once, then it pops memory error. I have been working with normal cause GetRulesCombinations(range(21), 13,21) which only gives 2 million combinations, which is fine. This one is 29 million combinations. Any alternative?